# New problem: Exception encountered during context initiali. - canc. refr. attem.: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, maven

this is my first post here. I am beginner. I am working on a spring boot application. After trying many solutions, it's not getting resolved.Please help (If any code snippet is missing, I'll send it.):

**Console:**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-05 19:02:21.266 ERROR 3484 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'doctorApiController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'doctorService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'doctorServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'doctorRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'doctorRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class io.swagger.model.Doctor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot.main(Swagger2SpringBoot.java:37) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'doctorServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'doctorRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'doctorRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class io.swagger.model.Doctor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'doctorRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class io.swagger.model.Doctor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class io.swagger.model.Doctor
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:181) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

**DoctorApiController:**

```
@Controller
public class DoctorApiController implements DoctorApi {
@Autowired
private doctorService doctorService;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DoctorApiController.class);

private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private final HttpServletRequest request;

@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
public DoctorApiController(ObjectMapper objectMapper, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.request = request;
}

public ResponseEntity<Doctor> addDooctor(@ApiParam(value = "Created doctor object" ,required=true )  @Valid @RequestBody Doctor body) {
    String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
    if (accept != null && accept.contains("application/json")) {

        io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot.ListD.add(body);
        //return new ResponseEntity<Doctor>(body, HttpStatus.OK );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(doctorService.addDoctor(body));
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Doctor>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

}


public ResponseEntity<Doctor> deleteDoctorById(
        @ApiParam(value = "Numeric ID of the user to get.", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
    if (accept != null && accept.contains("application/json")) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(doctorService.deleteDoctorById(id));

    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Doctor>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
public ResponseEntity<Doctors> findAllDoctors() {
    String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
    if (accept != null && accept.contains("application/json")) {

        Doctors sts = new Doctors2();
        sts.setDoctors(doctorService.findAllDoctors());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(sts);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Doctors>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}


public ResponseEntity<List<Doctor>> updateDoctor(@ApiParam(value = "name that need to be updated",required=true) @PathVariable("Doctorname") String Doctorname,@ApiParam(value = "Updated Doctor object" ,required=true )  @Valid @RequestBody Doctor body) {
    String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");

    if (accept != null && accept.contains("application/json")) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Doctor>>(io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot.ListD, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<List<Doctor>>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

}

**doctorService:**

```
package io.swagger.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.swagger.model.Doctor;
@Service
public interface doctorService {
    public Doctor addDoctor(Doctor doctor);
    public Doctor deleteDoctorById(long id);
    public List<Doctor> findAllDoctors();
    public Doctor updateDoctor(Doctor doctor);
    @Cacheable ("doctors")
    public Doctor findDoctorById(long id);
```

}

**doctorServiceImpl:**

```
package io.swagger.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import io.swagger.model.Doctor;


@Service
@Transactional
public class doctorServiceImpl implements doctorService {
    @Autowired
    private doctorRepository doctorRepository;
    @Transactional
    public void adddoctor(Doctor doctor){
        doctorRepository.saveAndFlush(doctor);
    }
    @Override
    public Doctor addDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        return doctorRepository.save(doctor);
    }   

    @Override
    public Doctor deleteDoctorById(long id) {
        Optional<Doctor> os = doctorRepository.findById(id);
        if(os.isPresent()) doctorRepository.deleteById(id);
        return os.get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Doctor> findAllDoctors() {
        return doctorRepository.findAll();
    }


    @Override
    public Doctor findDoctorById(long id) {
        Optional<Doctor> os = doctorRepository.findById(id);
        if(os.isPresent()) return os.get();
        else return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Doctor updateDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
        doctorRepository.updateDoctorById(doctor.getId(), doctor.getDoctorname(), doctor.getFirstName(), doctor.getLastName(), doctor.getEmail(), doctor.getPassword(), doctor.getPhone(), doctor.getAvatarUrl(), doctor.getDoctorvotes());
        return doctor;


    }
}
```

**doctorRepository:**

```
 package io.swagger.service;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import io.swagger.model.Doctor;

public interface doctorRepository extends JpaRepository<Doctor,Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Doctor s set s.id = ?1, s.doctorname = ?2, s.firstName = ?3, s.lastName = ?4, s.email = ?5, s.password = ?6, s.phone = ?7, s.avatarUrl = ?8, s.doctorvotes = ?9")

    void updateDoctorById(Integer id, String doctorname, String firstName, String lastName, String email,
            String password, String phone, String avatarUrl, Integer doctorvotes);
}
```

**"model.Doctor" is -> Doctor:**

```
package io.swagger.model;

import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

/**
 * Doctor
 */
@Validated
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2020-04-19T11:38:27.027Z")


@Table(name = "doctors")
@JsonRootName("Doctor")

public class Doctor   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Integer id = null;

  @JsonProperty("Doctorname")
  private String Doctorname = null;

  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  private String firstName = null;

  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  private String lastName = null;

  @JsonProperty("email")
  private String email = null;

  @JsonProperty("password")
  private String password = null;

  @JsonProperty("phone")
  private String phone = null;

  @JsonProperty("avatarUrl")
  private String avatarUrl = null;

  @JsonProperty("Doctorvotes")
  private Integer Doctorvotes = null;

  public Doctor id(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get id
   * @return id
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Doctor Doctorname(String Doctorname) {
    this.Doctorname = Doctorname;
    return this;
  }


  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getDoctorname() {
    return Doctorname;
  }

  public void setDoctorname(String Doctorname) {
    this.Doctorname = Doctorname;
  }

  public Doctor firstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get firstName
   * @return firstName
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public Doctor lastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get lastName
   * @return lastName
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public Doctor email(String email) {
    this.email = email;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get email
   * @return email
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public Doctor password(String password) {
    this.password = password;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get password
   * @return password
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public Doctor phone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get phone
   * @return phone
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }

  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  public Doctor avatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
    this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get avatarUrl
   * @return avatarUrl
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getAvatarUrl() {
    return avatarUrl;
  }

  public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
    this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
  }

  public Doctor Doctorvotes(Integer Doctorvotes) {
    this.Doctorvotes = Doctorvotes;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Doctor Number of votes
   * @return Doctorvotes
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Doctor Number of votes")


  public Integer getDoctorvotes() {
    return Doctorvotes;
  }

  public void setDoctorvotes(Integer Doctorvotes) {
    this.Doctorvotes = Doctorvotes;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Doctor doctor = (Doctor) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, doctor.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.Doctorname, doctor.Doctorname) &&
        Objects.equals(this.firstName, doctor.firstName) &&
        Objects.equals(this.lastName, doctor.lastName) &&
        Objects.equals(this.email, doctor.email) &&
        Objects.equals(this.password, doctor.password) &&
        Objects.equals(this.phone, doctor.phone) &&
        Objects.equals(this.avatarUrl, doctor.avatarUrl) &&
        Objects.equals(this.Doctorvotes, doctor.Doctorvotes);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, Doctorname, firstName, lastName, email, password, phone, avatarUrl, Doctorvotes);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class Doctor {\n");

    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    Doctorname: ").append(toIndentedString(Doctorname)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    firstName: ").append(toIndentedString(firstName)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    lastName: ").append(toIndentedString(lastName)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    email: ").append(toIndentedString(email)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    password: ").append(toIndentedString(password)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    phone: ").append(toIndentedString(phone)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    avatarUrl: ").append(toIndentedString(avatarUrl)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    Doctorvotes: ").append(toIndentedString(Doctorvotes)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) { 
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are posting a Stacktrace which contains several possible errors and also explanations. What is your question exactly. What have you tried to fix this error?

Comment: This is the code generated from swagger (yaml), to which I added a database based on the example sent by the teacher. I can't get rid of these mistakes, I don't have enough skills. Please help.

Comment: Read the Stacktrace, especially the first real long line, and try to understand what it tells you. Looks like some Annotation or Configuration is missing somewhere.

Comment: I will try it. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's having trouble creating the *doctorRepository* bean because the Doctor class isn't a managed entity (see the stacktrace).

You need to annotate your Doctor class with **@Entity** to make it a Spring managed entity.

Comment: It works but i needed add this:
  
 Id
 GeneratedValue
 Query(value = "example", nativeQuery = true)